# Sharepoint adding text description of a List Web Part

Tags: sharepoint, web-parts, content-editor

I wonder if there is a way to put a list and some text(rich text) in a web part.

I'm putting multiple web parts in a web part page, and there's some description of the list. If I insert another content editor web part above my list web part, the page looks fragmented and the user won't relate two web parts together.

I understand there's no way to put a web part into another. Any suggestion about what I can  do about it?

Comment: What is the version of SharePoint? What is the kind of website (template you choose)?L

Comment: I'm using SharePoint 2010. It's a web part page.

Answer (score 0):

Try using blank page. not a webpart page.
You can insert rich text on it at the same time you can insert webparts.

Comment: Thanks Aki. I can do that. What if I want to combine them together? So that it will look like: header title, text description and list content(from top to bottom).

Comment: Set the Chrome Type of the webpart to none so it will hide the header of the webpart.